# Does the function call have access or retain the value of a local var variable of its parent function because I declare that variable as var?

Tags: javascript, closures, var, let

I expect the calling of the first element in the array to print out the *number 0*. However, it prints *5*. Does the function call have access to `i` of its parent function because I declare `i` as `var`? If I declare `i` as a `let` variable, it prints *0* as expected.

**0-closureBug.js**

```
function makeFunctionArray() {
        const arr = []

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                arr.push(function() { console.log(i) })
        }

        console.log(i)

        return arr
}

const functionArr = makeFunctionArray()

functionArr[0]()
```

Comment: Every function has access to outer variables, no matter how they are declared. It's just that with `var` you have only one variable that will have the value `5` when you call the function, while with `let` every loop iteration has its own variable that doesn't change.

Comment: I thought the declarations of `i`s as `var`s are replaced with literal values of each statement in the function declaration, as the elements of the array as:  `console.log`, `console.log(0)`, `console.log(1)`, `console.log(2)`, `console.log(3)`, `console.log(4)`. However, its not as my expected

Comment: No, a closure really has access to the variable itself, and its *current value* - and it can even assign a value to the variable.